# installed modules not working in various python enviorments

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

- I am trying to use various imported modules such as, numpy, guiqwt,
  and matplotlib. When I import the modules I get:

  ```
             ModuleNotFoundError: No module named " "
  ```
- However, I have successfully installed all of these libraries using
  pip install.

  From what I have gathered so far, I do not think this is a problem
  with having dependencies to the modules and instead a path issue.

  I noticed this error on pyCharm and Idle, although is not occurring
  on Anaconda. I understand this may have to do with the fact that
  Anaconda installed its own Python (for lack of better terms).

Can someone help explain why this is happening?
Thanks in advance,

Here is a screenshot of my env. variables if it matters:

[a screenshot of my environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJt0w.png)

Comment: Most likely you installed these libraries to Anaconda and not the site-package in the global python

Comment: Did you specify which python environment you are using in your script before `import`ing a library?

Comment: No. And I installed Anaconda after I used the pip install function.

Comment: First of all, I'd recommend you to install libraries using the `conda install libraryname` command if possible. Type in `conda info --envs` to check how many environments you have, I assume you have more than one if you're getting this error. Then `activate` the environment you want and type `conda list` to see if the library is indeed there. If you installed the library before installing anaconda, the library will not be associated with anaconda.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.